# IIS 7 Disable Caching

Tags: php, iis-7, cache

Hi in my development machine I want to completely turn off caching (all types) for php. No matter what I try IIS 7 is still caching and it really drives me crazy!

Answer (score 3):

OK, this may be a late response, but i had a similar problem, that it turns out was caused by a PHP accelerator called wincache.

just comment out this line in php.ini 

[PHP_WINCACHE]
;extension=php_wincache.dll

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to find this:

**Output Caching**

Click on "Edit Feature Settings..."
Uncheck Enable cache and Enable kernel cache

**Application Pools**

Select your pool and click "Recycling..."
Check "Fixed number of requests"
Set to 1

This will force flush all caching.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the below mentioned entry in your applicationHost.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
    </caching>
</system.webServer>
```

Change the true to false and you should be good..

From UI,

Click on the Web Site -> **Output Caching**
click on **Edit Feature Settings...**
uncheck **Enable cache** and **Enable kernel cache**

Comment: both unchecked and set to false, still caching. my php file is so simple it just echo "somestring" but still caching about 1 minute.

Comment: if those parameters are false.. then i would check if PHP caching is enabled in the application.. check this article http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/10/31/PHP-on-IIS.aspx